# Permanent Permission on /dev/ttyS0 CentOS 6.4

Tags: centos, udev

I seem to be unable to change the permissions on the /dev/ttyS0 device of a CentOS 6.4 machine.

Every time I reboot, the system goes back to the defaults.

I've googled that I need to edit the udev rules, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Can someone help me?

Comment: @dawud In the future, please also remove greetings and signatures from posts. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines:

```
KERNEL=="ttyS[0-9]*", NAME="tts/%n", SYMLINK+="%k", GROUP="uucp", MODE="0666"
```

Can be easily found in you favourite search engine.

Check [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/udev-rules-and-ttys0-device-644237/).
Also check this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/192546/how-to-change-device-permissions-via-udev-in-rhel5).